# No sensors found to register step counter listening to

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Am trying to make an ionic3 pedometer application using the ionic pedometer plugin and running the finished application on my android device.

It fails to start with this error Message "No sensors found to register step counter listening to".

Please anyone with a solution please help with any other alternative plugin or way to get this working.

Comment: check if  `<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter"
        android:required="true"/>` is in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: thanks for the assistance,  let me check it  out will get back to you.

Comment: I have tried it but it gives another error, "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors"

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am late but this is the correct conclusion may be :

In some smartphones, there is simply no hardware sensor with which this plugin works, namely Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER

You can view its availability by an application like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z

In the absence of this sensor, the calculation of the number of steps is through interaction with the accelerometer, by analyzing and filtering data.

so that's the reason you was see this message.